# how to reference variables inside custom pgbench scripts?

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to write a custom pgbench script to benchmark a new postgres cluster that I'm setting up.  The official documentation makes it seem simple enough, however it looks like defined variables are not always interpreted if they lack trailing whitespace (or some other undocumented characters).  Here's the script (testlist_bska.sql) that I'm trying to run:

```
\setrandom aid 100 50875000
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nppsmoke_tmp_:aid CASCADE;
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE nppsmoke_tmp_:aid (testname text NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX nppsmoke_tmp_idx_:aid ON nppsmoke_tmp_:aid (testname);
COPY nppsmoke_tmp_:aid (testname) FROM '/tmp/testlist_p3_c.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, ESCAPE '~');

INSERT INTO nppsmoke_testlist (testname) SELECT a.testname FROM nppsmoke_tmp_:aid a LEFT JOIN nppsmoke_testlist b ON b.testname = a.testname WHERE b.testname IS NULL;
UPDATE nppsmoke_testlist set tstamp=now() WHERE testname IN (SELECT testname FROM nppsmoke_tmp_:aid );
DELETE FROM nppsmoke_testlist WHERE age(now(),tstamp) > INTERVAL '12 months';
DROP TABLE nppsmoke_tmp_:aid CASCADE;

COPY nppsmoke_testlist (id,testname) TO '/tmp/testlist_:aid' (DELIMITER ',');
\shell /bin/cp -f /tmp/scrub_9sBO.sql /tmp/scrub_csv.":aid"
\shell /bin/sed -i "s/,\"87692\",/,\":aid\",/g" /tmp/scrub_csv.":aid"
COPY nppsmoketests (last_update,current_status,testid,suiteid,regressioncl,testcl,os,arch,build_type,branch,gpu,subtest,osversion) FROM '/tmp/scrub_sql.:aid ' with CSV HEADER ESCAPE '~';
\shell /bin/rm -f /tmp/testlist_:aid /tmp/scrub_csv.":aid"
COMMIT;
```

However, when I invoke this script, it fails with the following output:

```
$ pgbench -U lfriedman -n -f testlist_bska.sql -t 1 nightly
NOTICE:  table "nppsmoke_tmp_39362939" does not exist, skipping
Client 0 aborted in state 13: ERROR:  could not open file "/tmp/scrub_csv.39362939 " for reading: No such file or directory
transaction type: Custom query
scaling factor: 1
query mode: simple
number of clients: 1
number of threads: 1
number of transactions per client: 1
number of transactions actually processed: 0/1
tps = 0.000000 (including connections establishing)
tps = 0.000000 (excluding connections establishing)
```

The other glaring problem is that I can't figure out how to get the sed command to correctly substitute the current value of the :aid variable for 87692.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up hacking up a workaround, as I couldn't get the variables to work reliably in the \shell commands if they weren't enclosed in whitespace.  What I did was create a shell script which was invoked via the \shell command, with parameters passed to it:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin:/root/bin
NUM="$1"
OPT="$2"

if [[ ${OPT} == 'setup' ]] ; then
        cp -f /tmp/scrub_9sBO.sql /tmp/scrub_csv.${NUM} && sed -i "s/87692/${NUM}/g" /tmp/scrub_csv.${NUM}
elif [[ ${OPT} == 'del' ]] ; then
        rm -f /tmp/testlist_${NUM} /tmp/scrub_csv.${NUM}
fi
```

Here's the new version of the pgbench script:

```
\setrandom aid 100 50875000
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nppsmoke_tmp_:aid CASCADE;
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE nppsmoke_tmp_:aid (testname text NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX nppsmoke_tmp_idx_:aid ON nppsmoke_tmp_:aid (testname);
COPY nppsmoke_tmp_:aid (testname) FROM '/tmp/testlist_p3_c.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, ESCAPE '~');

INSERT INTO nppsmoke_testlist (testname) SELECT a.testname FROM nppsmoke_tmp_:aid a LEFT JOIN nppsmoke_testlist b ON b.testname = a.testname WHERE b.testname IS NULL;
UPDATE nppsmoke_testlist set tstamp=now() WHERE testname IN (SELECT testname FROM nppsmoke_tmp_:aid );
DELETE FROM nppsmoke_testlist WHERE age(now(),tstamp) > INTERVAL '12 months';
DROP TABLE nppsmoke_tmp_:aid CASCADE;

COPY nppsmoke_testlist (id,testname) TO '/tmp/testlist_:aid' (DELIMITER ',');
\shell /tmp/bm.sh :aid setup
COPY nppsmoketests (last_update,current_status,testid,suiteid,regressioncl,testcl,os,arch,build_type,branch,gpu,subtest,osversion) FROM '/tmp/scrub_csv.:aid' with CSV HEADER ESCAPE '~';
\shell /tmp/bm.sh :aid del
COMMIT;
```